# How to implement maintenance mode in Nuxt 3 with a global middleware?

Tags: redirect, nuxt.js, middleware

I'm trying to implement a maintenance mode in my Nuxt 3 application. I have created a middleware (`maintenance.global.ts`) that I want to run on every page call and change, whether it's through a `nuxt-link` or a `router-link`. However, I'm encountering an issue where the middleware only runs when the page is reloaded, and it's not called when the page is changed via a `nuxt-link`.

**Example:**

I start by visiting "http://localhost:3000", and I'm automatically redirected to "/status/maintenance" when maintenance mode is enabled. However, if I use `nuxt-link` to navigate to another page like "/legal/imprint" and then try to return to the index page, I'm no longer redirected and remain on "http://localhost:3000".

Here's the code for my middleware:

**~/middleware/maintenance.global.ts**

```js
export default defineNuxtRouteMiddleware((to, from) => {
    let isMaintenance = process.env.MAINTENANCE;
    let allowedRoutes = [
        '/status/maintenance',
        '/legal/imprint'
    ];

    if (!isMaintenance) return;

    if (isMaintenance === 'true' && !allowedRoutes.includes(to.path)) {
        return navigateTo('/status/maintenance');
    } else if (isMaintenance === 'false' && to.path === '/status/maintenance') {
        return navigateTo('/');
    }
})
```

And here's the content of my `~/.env` file:

**~/.env**

```
MAINTENANCE=true
```

I want to ensure that the maintenance middleware runs when changing pages using `nuxt-link`. What could be causing this issue, and how can I make the middleware work as expected?